# Does Python's PEP8 line length limit apply to comments?

Tags: python, pep8

I am working on a collaborative Python project. My IDE (PyCharm) flags 'minor issues' for lines of code being more than 120 characters long because of PEP8. However, this only occurs when I have a large comment explaining some complicated code - the code itself never exceeds the limit. Should I turn these long comments into multiple line comments to keep to the guidelines or leave them as they are?

Comment: generally, pep8 guidelines allow 79 characters in a line. it applies for comments as well, but again those are just guidelines. Following pep8 is just about maintaining consistency in your code.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion/style and does not have a useful answer.  I suggest putting long comments above the line they pertain to but that varies.  Also pep8 is just a suggestion, not a mandate.

Comment: Yes, PEP-8 line length applies to comments too. You didn't say whether these were inline comments or on a separate line to the code, but FWIW, PEP-8 recommends that  inline comments be used sparingly.

Comment: Based on personal preference and perhaps a little instinct, I would make your comments multi-line.  Found PEP8 and it's actually 79 chars limit and yes, PEP8 provides "coding conventions"

Comment: I don’t understand where the 79-character limit is supposed to have come from. Even in the old days of timesharing DEC PDP-11 and VAX machines, terminals and printers could do 132 columns.

Comment: @Lawrence D'Oliveiro  It might come from punch cards.  Also, the original IBM PC(and by extension any PC in text mode) has a display of 80x25(command line linux uses graphics mode to get higher character density).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the guidelines apply to **all** lines in the source, including comments. That's because they help set expectations for editor widths. If the line length recommendation did not apply to comments, you still had to scroll your editor window to be able to read the comments.

PEP8 is still a guideline, not a strict rule of law, you can ignore it at will. I recommend sticking to it anywhere you collaborate with a wider range of people however, even if you all have wider screens. Personally, I like being able to fit multiple editor tabs side by side, for example.

At Facebook, we use [`flake8-bugbear`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-bugbear) to *soft*-enforce line lengths, with a tolerance of 10%:

> B950: Line too long. This is a pragmatic equivalent of pycodestyle’s E501: it considers “max-line-length” but only triggers when the value has been exceeded by more than 10%. You will no longer be forced to reformat code due to the closing parenthesis being one character too far to satisfy the linter. At the same time, if you do significantly violate the line length, you will receive a message that states what the actual limit is. This is inspired by Raymond Hettinger’s “Beyond PEP 8” talk and highway patrol not stopping you if you drive < 5mph too fast. Disable E501 to avoid duplicate warnings.

*Oblig disclaimer*: I contribute to flake8-bugbear.